# Logcat floating window is read-only

Tags: android-studio

I am running Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

When the Logcat window is "Dock pinned", then I can enter new lines in the Logcat window, so it is easier to see when the app writes new entries.

However, when I switch it to "Float" (so I can see it side by side with the emulator), then when I try to enter new lines, it refuses and show the message "This view is read-only".

Is this by design?

I can work around it, if I switch to "Window", but I'd prefer the floating window.